# 'str' object has no attribute 'META' error while creating a ModelForm in django

Tags: django-forms

I'm trying to create a ModelForm with the following code snippet. I get this error "'str' object has no attribute 'META'". Why is that? Thanks

In my_app/forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
            model = User
```

In may_app/views.py

```
def u(request):
    form = UserProfileForm()
    return render('/projects/templates/form.html',{'form':form})
```

Answer (score 11):

```
def u(request):
    form = UserProfileForm()
    return render(request,'/projects/templates/form.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: you should also note the difference

Comment: For the sake of clarity: `render` expects `request` as the first parameter

Comment: can I pick @DanielHepper comment as the valid answer? ^^

Answer (score 0):

it means you're passing string where it expects something else,
for example I got the same error for writing

`model = 'User'`

but your sample looks ok, so it may not be the case...

and just btw: django has [generic view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login) for login pages like this